# MS Access: SQL to insert tab separated value file into a table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've managed to insert the contents of a comma separated txt file using the SQL command

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO [" + tableName + "] SELECT * FROM [text;database=" + filePath + "].[" + fileName + "]";
```

Is there a way to modify this command for tab separated values or more generally to allow a custom delimiter? Please note that the database is of type .mbd, not SQL Server.

Comment: Use a parameterized query to do the insert

Comment: @RajMore: Wouldn't that require reading in the file? Can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: How big are the files?

Comment: @RajMore: <= 5000 lines.

Comment: If a 5k file has 400 char on each line, you're looking at 2MB per row.  Are you sure you have a good enough reason for each row to be 2MB of data?

Comment: Not sure what is a syntax for MS Access. But I did import files into SQL Server with BULK Import. See this reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx Maybe there is similar syntax in Access.

Comment: @RajMore where are you getting 2 MB per row from? 400 char --> 64 kB per row, no? Also, I don't think you can parameterize a from clause in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all I needed to do was to add a Schema.ini file to the directory housing the text file. I did this as follows:

```
string schemaFilePath = filePath + "\\" + "Schema.ini";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(schemaFilePath, false);
writer.WriteLine("[" + fileName + "]");
writer.WriteLine("Format=TabDelimited");
writer.Close();
```

I did in a loop and deleted the schema file after executing the insert command.

Answer (score 1):

Import using External Data > Import & Link > Text File
Save that import then use that [Saved Import](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/run-a-saved-import-or-export-operation-HA001226020.aspx) from here on out.

Depending on your data if might be best to import into a staging table before doing validation checks, then import into your real table.

See also:
[Programmatically import CSV data to Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813947/programmatically-import-csv-data-to-access)

[How can I modify a saved Microsoft Access 2007 or 2010 Import Specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143420/how-can-i-modify-a-saved-microsoft-access-2007-or-2010-import-specification)